# I cannot use multiprocessing in IPython

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arcgis

Last year I wrote a simple code to mosaic hundreds of raster data. It went well.
Last week I picked up this code to do the same work, but it didn't work.
I copy the official demo:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

But there is no feedback, no report error. If I switch multiprocessing module to Thread module, it goes well.
Then I find out that the the demo can be ran in Python console but not in IPython console.
PS, I use WinPython-64bit, and have tried 2.7 and 3.5 version, both have the same problem. And I cannot use multiprocessing module in the ArcGIS python console.
Thanks

Comment: Why cannot I use Process in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I have not understand your question that much.

but, if you want to use Thread, you can try this.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPool(4)           # 4 is number of your CPU core, 4 times faster
    names = ['bob','jack','newt']  #prepare your name list 
    results = pool.map(f, names)
    pool.close()  
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Actually Thread works fine, but not multiprocessing.I have tried your code, it  runs well. Why I cannot run multiprocessing?

Comment: @ZheYang, maybe try uninstall and install, nothing can't be solve by this way. If have, try again.